# trying to understand how one is expected to use web workers in Angular

Tags: angular

The angular docs say to do:
`ng g web-worker <location>`

And an example is given for newing up a worker:

```
const worker = new Worker(new URL('./app.worker', import.meta.url));
```

When I tried doing this, I am seeing:

```
DOMException: Failed to construct 'Worker': Script at 'file:///Users/me/my/project/workers/my.worker' cannot be accessed from origin 'http://localhost:4200'.
```

Is Angular's example code not meant to be run locally?

Do I need to just make an api endpoint on a web server that serves this worker file?  I am confused, because the ng generate command made a ts config file for workers, which seems to serve no purpose if you're going to be serving the file separately from a web server...  So I am just wondering how do developers currently make use of workers with Angular in a way that works both in development and production?

Comment: I have the same issue. The example on Angular.io continues to show the code you have above, but it does not actually work. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @TimGallagher I did get it working, that was so long ago I am trying to remember what the problem was, I am pretty sure I just was missing the tsconfig for the workers...  So I answered my question with that.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add to angular.json under the architect build object:

```
"webWorkerTsConfig": "tsconfig.worker.json"
```

and then that tsconfig.worker.json file looks like:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/worker",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "webworker"
    ],
   "types": [],
  },
  "include": [
    "src/@types/**/*.d.ts",
    "src/**/*.worker.ts"
  ]
}
```